# Transactional SpringJUnit4 Test Failure

Tags: spring, jpa, junit, aspectj, spring-roo

Our transactional JUnit tests for our Spring web application fail.

Specifically: If I execute each test with maven separately they run through:

```
mvn -Dtest=Test1
mvn -Dtest=Test2
```

If I execute

```
mvn -Dtest=Test1,Test2
```

I get a JPA error in one of the tests:

```
Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is
    java.lang.IllegalStateException:
        Attempting to execute an operation on a closed EntityManagerFactory."
        type="org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException"
        org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException:
            Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is
                java.lang.IllegalStateException:
                    Attempting to execute an operation on a closed EntityManagerFactory.
                        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.verifyOpen(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:338)
                        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:303)
                        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336)
                        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:302)
                        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.createEntityManagerForTransaction(JpaTransactionManager.java:449)
                        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:369)
                        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
                        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:439)
                        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
                        at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:64)
                        ...
```

They also run through if I set the surefire plugin to recreate the whole JVM for each test, which ofcourse takes an insane amount of time.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
        <forkCount>1</forkCount>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Application setup:

- Spring, with Spring Roo (thus proxymode=asjectJ !)
- Eclipselink as JPA Provider

ApplicationContext.xml for test setup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="[packagename]">
    <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*" type="regex" />
    <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation" />
</context:component-scan>
<context:spring-configured />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties" />
<context:annotation-config />

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"
    transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${test_database.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${test_database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${test_database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${test_database.password}" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="true" />
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000" />
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3" />
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
</bean>

<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource"
    ignore-failures="ALL">
    <jdbc:script location="${test_database.selectLocation}" />
    <jdbc:script location="${test_database.initLocation}" />
    <jdbc:script location="${test_database.dataLocation}" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>
</beans>
```

The JUnit Tests look like:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml",
    "classpath:META-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager")
@DirtiesContext
public class Test1 {

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
      this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void getJSONTest() throws Exception {
    ...
    }
}
```

Does anybody have any idea, how two of those tests are connected? One must close the entityManager for the other , but why and how?

Any thoughts are appreciated!

**Edit1**: Removed @TransactionConfiguration and @DirtiesContext as proposed, but now I get an

```
No transaction is currently active; nested exception is
    javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException
```

**Edit2**: I tracked down the issue so far that the order in which I execute the tests plays a hole. Hence, the tests are not independent of each other. I tried several permutations of annotations and execution orders resulting every time in different errors/behavior.

Right now the setup on class level is:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml",
    "classpath:META-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml" })
@WebAppConfiguration
@Transactional
@DirtiesContext
```

I put the @DirtiesContext annotation again, because a newly initialized context seems to help sometimes.

It's hard to track down the real issue here, but I came to one concrete Question:

I wrapped my test class in @Transactional and in my test method I call

```
mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(...))
```

, calling a controller method. This controller method delegates to another bean, that has a @Transactional method. After the mockMvc.perform() returns, I'am checking in the unit test weather the value has been writting to the database. I am aware that this can only work if either the transaction is committed to the database, or the same Transaction/entityManager is used. Is the transaction of the test method, the same as the one of the called controller or are we talking about two different entityManagers/transactions here?

Answer (score -1):

I'd say that @DirtiesContext is doing that - see here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html

I would try to:

1. Remove @TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager") - I believe that's not necessary according to your spring xml configuration
2. Remove @DirtiesContext

And then try if situation improved... 
This is setup I use for testing DAO layer (each method actually reaches real database, but thanks to @Rollback the database is never changed by the test, therefore tests are not interfering each other)

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = RealDbDAOTests.class)
@Transactional
@Rollback
public class DaoTests {
 ....
}
```

Comment: Sorry, for "unaccepting" the answer, but I just noticed that the JPA error has gone away, but now I have a "Exception Description: No transaction is currently active;" Error :/

Comment: Hm, and do you have the @Transactional annotatinon there? Can you please post how your test class annotation configuration looks like now?